# hadoop pig : join on a condition (ex. tab1.COL1 LIKE (%tab2.col2%) )

Tags: hadoop, join, apache-pig

How to implement a join on a condition in PIG?
SQL equivalent Examples:

```
       select * from tab1, tab2 where instr(t1.col1,t2.col1 ) > 1 ;
       select * from tab1, tab2 where f(t1.col1) =f(t2.col1)  ;
```

Thank you very much.
Filippo

Answer (score 0):

As of now pig supports only Inner Joins,Outer Joins and Full Joins. second Join example can be implemented in Pig, not the other one. Below is an example.

```
tab1 = LOAD 'file1' using PigStorage('|') using (col1:chararray,col2:chararray);
tab2 = LOAD 'file2' using PigStorage('|') using (col1:chararray,col2:chararray);
result = JOIN tab1 by col1, tab2 by col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1.

```
Cross_Table = CROSS tab1, tab2;
Filter_Table = FILTER Cross_Table BY NOT(STARTSWITH(tab1::col1, tab2::col1));
```

2.

```
Join_Table = JOIN tab1 BY f(col1) INNER JOIN, tab2 BY f(col1);
```